# Use of S3 in Terraform aws_instance.connection.private_key and aws_key_pair.public_key

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am trying to use **terraform cloud** and don't want to commit SSH key inside the repository. My current configuration looks like this:

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "project" {
  key_name   = "project"
  public_key = file(".ssh/id_rsa.pub")
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-08ee2516c7709ea48"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = [
    aws_security_group.ssh_allow.name,
    aws_security_group.http_allow.name
  ]
  key_name = aws_key_pair.project.key_name

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "centos"
    private_key = file(".ssh/id_rsa")
    host        = self.public_ip
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo yum -y install nginx",
      "sudo systemctl start nginx"
    ]
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
```

Is it possible to reference the file from remote storage, for example S3?

something like this:

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "project" {
  key_name   = "project"
  public_key = s3_file("bucket/ssh/id_rsa.pub")
}
```

## Is it at all possible?

I have tried to use **data** providers

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "public_key" {
  bucket = "com.project.infrastructure"
  key    = ".ssh/project.pub"
}

data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "private_key" {
  bucket = "com.project.infrastructure"
  key    = ".ssh/project"
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "project" {
  key_name   = "project"
  public_key = data.aws_s3_bucket_object.public_key.body
}
```

but getting this error:

```sh
Error: "public_key": required field is not set

  on example.tf line 28, in resource "aws_key_pair" "project":
  28: resource "aws_key_pair" "project" {
```

AWS security credentials are correct and I can download file from the bucket with

```sh
aws s3api get-object --bucket com.project.infrastructure --key .ssh/project private_key
```

## Experiment with null_resource also failed

```
resource "null_resource" "download_key" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = create
    command = "aws s3api get-object --bucket com.project.infrastructure --key .ssh/project.pub project.pub"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = create
    command = "aws s3api get-object --bucket com.project.infrastructure --key .ssh/project project"
  }
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "project" {
  key_name   = "project"
  depends_on = [null_resource.download_key]
  public_key = file("project.pub")
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-08ee2516c7709ea48"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = [
    aws_security_group.ssh_allow.name,
    aws_security_group.http_allow.name
  ]
  key_name = aws_key_pair.project.key_name

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "centos"
    private_key = file("project")
    host        = self.public_ip
  }


  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${aws_instance.example.public_ip} > ip_address.txt"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo yum -y install nginx",
      "sudo systemctl start nginx"
    ]
  }

  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.saritasa_bucket, aws_key_pair.project]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  tags = module.project_config.tags

}
```

**then I get the following error**:

```
➜ terraform plan    

Error: Error in function call

  on example.tf line 42, in resource "aws_key_pair" "project":
  42:   public_key = file("proect.pub")

Call to function "file" failed: no file exists at project.pub.
```

Answer (score 1):

One option will be to call your `aws s3api get-object` from a null resource
then use depends_on on your `aws_key_pair` resource

Something like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "random_string" "key" {
  length  = 8
  special = false
}

resource "null_resource" "download_key" {
  triggers = {
    build_number = timestamp()
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = create
    command = "aws s3api get-object --bucket bucket123456123654 --key dir/data ${path.module}/${random_string.key.result}"
  }
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "project" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.download_key]
  key_name   = "project"
  public_key = file("${path.module}/${random_string.key.result}")
}
```

Comment: this didn't work. I have updated my original question with modified terraform code and error I get. In short I get the error `Call to function "file" failed: no file exists at project.pub.`. So it seems validation for existence of the file happens at Plan step and therefore null resource is not invoked here.

Comment: ...and for the record there is nothing wrong with adding your **PUBLIC** key to your repo... the one you should not add is your private one

Comment: I updated my answer to include relative path also use `random_string` for file name ... but I feel this is a hack, you should just add your public key to the repo